# Python - Arranging combinations of list into a list of tuples of various sizes

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples, combinations

I have a list of strings:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to create all possible combinations of the list elements in groups of different sizes. I would prefer this to be a list of tuples of tuples, but it could also be a list of lists of lists, etc. The orders of the tuples, and of the tuples in the tuples, does not matter. No list element can be repeated in either the tuples or the tuples of tuples. For the above list, I would expect something like:

```
[(('a'),('b'),('c')),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c')),
 (('a', 'c'), ('b')),
 (('b', 'c'), ('a')),
 (('a', 'b', 'c'))]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I do require that each of the tuples in the list contain all of the elements of l. 
senderle and Antimony, you are both correct regarding the omissions.

Comment: Did you mean to have `a, (b,c,d)` in there too?

Comment: This function `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` may be helpful for you.

Comment: Don't `(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))`, `(('b', 'c'), ('a', 'd'))`, and `(('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'))` belong in the output too?

Comment: @gavinmh Maybe a shorter example input would make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do things. I don't know if there are any more elegant methods. The `itertools` module has functions for combinations and permutations, but unfortunately, nothing for partitions.

Edit: My first version isn't correct, but fortunately, I already have this lying around from an old project I did.

You can also get a unique integer key that represents an edge bitset associated with each partition by returning `d` instead of `d.values()`. This is useful for efficiently testing whether one partition is a refinement of another.

```
def connectivityDictSub(num, d, setl, key, i):
    if i >= num:
        assert(key not in d)
        d[key] = setl
    else:
        for ni in range(len(setl)):
            nsetl, nkey = setl[:], key
            for other in nsetl[ni]:
                assert(other != i)
                x,y = sorted((i, other))
                ki = ((2*num-3-x)*x)/2 + y-1
                nkey |= 1<<ki
            nsetl[ni] = nsetl[ni] + [i] #not the same as += since it makes a copy
            connectivityDictSub(num, d, nsetl, nkey, i+1)
        nsetl = setl + [[i]]
        connectivityDictSub(num, d, nsetl, key, i+1)

def connectivityDict(groundSet):
    gset = sorted(set(groundSet))
    d = {}
    connectivityDictSub(len(gset), d, [], 0, 0)
    for setl in d.values():
        setl[:] = [tuple(gset[i] for i in x) for x in setl]
    return map(tuple, d.values())

for x in connectivityDict('ABCD'):
    print x
```

Comment: Should this be `for b in xrange(1 << n):`? That generates more possibilities and it looks correct.

Comment: `n-1` is intentional. All `n` will do is generate duplicates with an empty set on the front half the time.

Comment: I think it's a little trickier: we need to get things like `(('a', 'd'), ('b'), ('c'))` too.

Comment: Nice catch! I'll need to adjust things a little.

Comment: I just remembered that I already did this last year, so fortunately I still have the code lying around.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, or at least counting seems to give the Bell numbers, which is a good check.  (Assuming that the OP really wants set partitions, despite the missing elements.)  TAOCP has a fast algorithm, natch.

Answer (score 2):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html%20itertools) should do most of the job you want.

Example:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
    print(subset)
```

The example is just to show itertools. You will have to figure it out to get the exact output you want.

Comment: Itertools doesn't have any functions for partitions, like the asker appears to want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified more clearly that each top-level tuple in the list should contain all of the elements from l.

Comment: No worries I know that itertools alone does not do the job. Just trying to point the way. =)